# scala open frame on button click

Tags: swing, scala

I am creating a application in scala. I want to open a frame on button click. I am new to scala. Here is the code

```
 import scala.swing._;
 import java.io._;
 import scala.swing.event._;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

object Try1 extends SimpleSwingApplication {
def top = new MainFrame {
title = "First Swing App";

val button = new Button {
  text = "Proceed"
}
contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {


  contents += button

  border = Swing.EmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30)
}
val obj = new Try2();
listenTo(button)

reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(button) =>
   //here 2nd frame must be open

 }
}
```

The code for window to be opened goes like this

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon
import scala.swing._

class Try2 extends SimpleSwingApplication {
 def top = new MainFrame {
 title = "Second Swing App";

val button = new Button {
  text = "Proceed"
}
contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {


  contents += button

  border = Swing.EmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30)
    }
  }
}
```

How can I open new window. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this as shown below. Here intentionally I am creating a new instance of Try2 instead of `obj` created earlier since this is a cleaner approach.

```
reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(x: Button) if x.text == "Proceed"  =>
    new Try2().top.visible = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day